# Exception in Base64 decoding?

Tags: java, encryption, nullpointerexception

I encountered a problem decoding text files.

Encryption works, but when the program is restarted, decryption throws an exception. The same similar `Exception` was thrown with `apache.common.Base64`.
Maybe someone knows how to solve this?

```
private String decrypt(String encrypted) throws Exception {
    Cipher cipher = getCipher(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE);
    //byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.decodeBase64(encrypted));

    /*this line throw an exception*/                                      
    byte[] plainBytes = cipher.doFinal(Base64.getDecoder().decode(encrypted));

    return new String(plainBytes);
}

private Cipher getCipher(int cipherMode) throws Exception {
    String encryptionAlgorithm = "AES";
    SecretKeySpec keySpecification = new SecretKeySpec(
            encryptionKey.getBytes("UTF-8"), encryptionAlgorithm);
    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance(encryptionAlgorithm);
    cipher.init(cipherMode, keySpecification);

    return cipher;
}




Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
at java.util.Base64$Decoder.decode(Base64.java:549)
at edmaker.EdMaker.decrypt(EdMaker.java:148)
```

Listening on javadebug
Not able to submit breakpoint MethodBreakpoint [fsiteratetest.FsIterateTest$1].visitFile '(Ljava/nio/file/Path;LBasicFileAttributes;)Ljava/nio/file/FileVisitResult;', reason: Breakpoint belongs to disabled source root 'C:\Users\win7p\Documents\NetBeansProjects\FsIterateTest\src'. See Window/Debugging/Sources.
User program running
User program stopped
Debugger stopped on uncompilable source code.
User program running
User program finished

Comment: Debugging and breakpoints do wonders. Check what exactly is null. Could `encrypted` (most likely since that `decodeBase64` function already throws the nullpointer exception), or `getCipher()` returned something null therefore `cipher`is null.

Comment: Obviously `encrypted` is null.

Comment: Somehow I know what is a NullPointerException, but I can't find the exceptional error in the code above. Maybe I should post the whole code ? Okay I should also take a look at debugging if I can.

Comment: Yes it is that encrypted is null. However I can't find the problem in BufferedReader when the String lines are parsed to the method. Thanks